# Subsetting dataframe for plot results in object not found error

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, with-statement

I have the following dataframe called plants:

```
    > head(plants)
     test.plant   test.soil root shoot total.dry.weight.plant phyl.distance.test.
1 pla med_plant plalan_soil  168   292                    460          0.05424804
2 pla med_plant plalan_soil  292   406                    698          0.05424804
3 pla med_plant plalan_soil  227   622                    849          0.05424804
4 pla med_plant plalan_soil  181   409                    590          0.05424804
5 pla med_plant plalan_soil  287   494                    781          0.05424804
6 pla med_plant plalan_soil  312   430                    742          0.05424804
```

I would like to create a plot with total.dry.weight.plant (y value) and phyl.distance.test (x value) for **every test.plant.** However, I get the same error with all my tries:

```
 plants[plants$test.plant == fespra_plant,]
Error in `[.data.frame`(plants, plants$test.plant == fespra_plant, ) : 
  object 'fespra_plant' not found
```

This is my code:

```
plants = read.csv("C:/Users../plants.csv",TRUE,sep=',')

DW = plants$total.dry.weight.plant
PD = plants$phyl.distance.test.

with(plants[plants$test.plant == fespra_plant,], plot(PD, DW))
```

How can I achieve to make plots for every test.plant species?

Why does the code above if it works well still plots every thing?

Comment: You need the `$` notation every time you're referring to a column in your dataframe.  Try `plants[plants$test.plant == plants$fespra_plant,]` instead

Comment: I think you want `plants[plants$test.plant == "fespra_plant",]` Otherwise R assumes `fespra_plant` is a variable rather than a value.

Comment: Thank you MrFlick. However, the code 
with(plants[plants$test.plant == "fespra_plant",], plot(PD, DW))
 gives us all datapoints of all plants.. so no subset.. Do you know how this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Consider `by` to plot across all subsets of *test.plant* factor:

```
by(plants, plants$test.plant, function(sub) {
     DW <- sub$total.dry.weight.plant
     PD <- sub$phyl.distance.test.

     with(sub, plot(DW, PD))
})
```